# Preventing SQL Injection in DAO Layer

Tags: jdbc

Assume that we have data inside the DTOObject

```
public void loginUser(UserDTO)
{

String name = UserDTO.getName();
String pwd = UserDTO.getPassword();
String sql  = "select UNAME , PWD from LoginTable where uname='"+name+"' and PWD='"+pwd+"';
}
```

Please tell me in this code , how can we prevent SQL Injection ?? How can we check for Malicious characters ??

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to move SQL from the DTO, where it doesn't belong, to the DAO, where it belongs, and use PreparedStatement there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on using `PreparedStatement` in JDBC. There are also plenty of others if you search around.

For the record, I must say that I disagree with the claim that the main advantage of a prepared statement is that it can be (though isn't necessarily) sent to the database in advance. The main advantage is parameters.